# Implemented AWS cognito authentication on login screen, API is being hit on UWP and android platform but not on IOS

Tags: ios, macos, amazon-web-services, xamarin, simulator

Built an app on xamarin for all three environments. Implemented AWS cognito authentication on login screen, API is being hit on UWP and android platform but not on IOS. Internet is working on the simulator but the API is not getting hit.  I've added Xcode in the firewall to. Did Not change the info.plist as the URL is already http secured. Can anyone suggest whats wrong?

Comment: which tutorial or sample  did you follow ,can you attach the link?

Comment: I'm creating my own app, i found that IOS simulator is not letting me hit any APIs or HTTP services through company network. But its working fine when connected to USB dongle internet. I have added the proxies too still not helping.

Comment: Can you provide the exception thrown when the API's that are not being hit?

Comment: The API hit was being blocked by my company network, the issue is sorted now. Thanks.